# Edit a Zsh command with external editor and replace the original command

Tags: zsh

I'm using Zsh with [Zim](https://github.com/zimfw/zimfw). I've set up a key binding for editing the current command in Neovim by placing the following into `.zshrc`:

```bsh
bindkey -v
export VISUAL=nvim
autoload edit-command-line; zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey -M vicmd v edit-command-line
```

With this, when I finish editing the command, the end result is placed under the original, like in the screenshot below.

[image: Example with two lines, with a command on each one.]

What I'd like to have instead is that the the end result *replaces* the original line. The main reason for this is that I'm using Powerlevel10k with [transient prompt](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#transient-prompt) enabled. This feature doesn't work in this particular case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Powerlevel10k.

When transient prompt is enabled, Powerlevel10k *should* truncate prompt when you finish editing the command in an external editor. It doesn't, however. I've just [fixed it](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/commit/b673e6a7dde2a91a00a72614fbbce8e1e9f28f2c) thanks to your report.

Now back to your original question.

> What I'd like to have instead is that the the end result *replaces* the original line.

You'll need to define a custom zle widget for that. Here's one implementation:

```bsh
function edit-command-line-inplace() {
  if [[ $CONTEXT != start ]]; then
    if (( ! ${+widgets[edit-command-line]} )); then
      autoload -Uz edit-command-line
      zle -N edit-command-line
    fi
    zle edit-command-line
    return
  fi
  () {
    emulate -L zsh -o nomultibyte
    local editor=("${(@Q)${(z)${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-vi}}}}") 
    case $editor in
      (*vim*)
        "${(@)editor}" -c "normal! $(($#LBUFFER + 1))go" -- $1
      ;;
      (*emacs*)
        local lines=("${(@f)LBUFFER}") 
        "${(@)editor}" +${#lines}:$((${#lines[-1]} + 1)) $1
      ;;
      (*)
        "${(@)editor}" $1
      ;;
    esac
    BUFFER=$(<$1)
    CURSOR=$#BUFFER
  } =(<<<"$BUFFER") </dev/tty
}
```

You can bind it the same way as you did with `edit-command-line`:

```bsh
zle -N edit-command-line-inplace
bindkey -M vicmd v edit-command-line-inplace
```

Note that `edit-command-line-inplace` defers to `edit-command-line` if it's impossible to update the command line inplace. For example, try typing `echo 'first line`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then invoke `edit-command-line-inplace`. There is no way to update the first line of the command, so `edit-command-line-inplace` will behave the same way as `edit-command-line`.

Edit: The first version of `edit-command-line-inplace` that I've posted explicitly invoked `nvim` to edit the command line. I've updated the code to respect `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` environment variables.

Comment: I use `code -n -w` to use with `edit-command-line`. How can I use vscode with `edit-command-line-inplace`.

Comment: @blueray I've updated the implementation of `edit-command-line-inplace` to respect `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` environment variables. If you set `VISUAL="code -n -w"` in your `~/.zshrc`, it should work.

Comment: I think I know you from zsh mailing list.